# colorbox with iframe can't be closed with keyboard navigation in Firefox

Tags: colorbox, section508, wcag2.0

I am trying to get Colorbox to work with keyboard navigation (tab navigation) when loading an iframe as the Colorbox content.  I am unable to escape the iframe content to get to the Close button in Firefox.  In other words, there is a keyboard trap when using Firefox, and one can never close the modal box.  It does work in Webkit (Safari / Chrome) and IE.

You can reproduce this using the Iframe example on the Colorbox site:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

- select Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube) or Outside Webpage (Iframe)

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: This is actually a bug in all Firefox versions. This bug is reported in 2012, and it still exists: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=814977